Replacement for content_entity migrate source plugin
I've been using the content_entity migrate source plugin for updating content structure within a site — for example, if I want to change a field's type, or move a subset of nodes of one content type to a new content type.
The content_entity plugin is provided by the migrate_drupal module, which depends on phpass, which we had to uninstall.
Is there some other migrate source plugin that provides similar functionality?
